# mysql transfer query

Tags: mysql

I updated the way my program works with fines and charges and now I need to transfer/migrate the old data to the new format. The way it used to work was fines/charges were stored in a field on the users's record. Now there is an entirely new table used to track each charge. I'd like to simply take that charge field and and 1 record to the billing table with that charge.

```
User table: id as INT, name as VARCHAR, charges as DECIMAL(10, 2)
Charge Table: id as INT, user_id as INT, amount as DOUBLE, type as INT, date_applied as DATETIME, description as VARCHAR
```

Lets say I have a user record: `(id => 1, name => 'john doe', charges => 4.20)` and want to transfer that to a charge record of

```
(id => 1, user_id => 1, amount => 4.20, type => 1, date_applied => (whatever  time the transfer is taking place), description => 'Initial balance')
```

How can I do this one time transfer in a SQL query? I'd rather not write up a PHP script for this one time deal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you want.

```
INSERT INTO `Charge Table` SELECT NULL, id, charges, 1, NOW(), 'Initial balance' FROM `User Table`
```

Comment: So if I understand correctly, this should work? 

 INSERT INTO `bills` (id, patron_id, amount, item_id, description, date_charged, type) VALUES( SELECT NULL, id, fines, null, 'Initial balance', NOW(), 1 FROM `patrons` )

Comment: actually, that didn't. I tried it and I got an error near  'SELECT NULL, id, fines, null,

Comment: No, you don't need the `VALUES` or the parens. You could do just `INSERT INTO bills (id, patron_id, amount, item_id, description, date_charged, type) SELECT NULL, id, fines, null, 'Initial balance', NOW(), 1 FROM patrons`